# How to get custom dialog activity while clicking on a button in listview in android?

Tags: android, android-adapter

> here is my code for ArrayAdapter. When i click on LinearLayout "cat" it gives error on dialog.show(). I don't know how to create custom dialog within ArrayAdapter class.
>   Everything work fine when i remove creating dialog part.
>
> Thanks in advance

**CategoryAdapter.java**

```js
public class CategoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;

    String[] menu = new String[25] ;
    String[] menu2 = new String[25];
    String[] menu3 = new String[25];
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    viewholder vh;
   
    public CategoryAdapter(Context context,    String [] menu,String [] menu2,String [] menu3) {
        super(context, R.layout.categoryadapter, menu);
        this.context = context;
        this.menu = menu;
        this.menu2=menu2;
        this.menu3=menu3;
    }
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        {
            vh=new viewholder();
            if (inflater == null)
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categoryadapter, parent, false);
            vh.cat=(LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category);
            convertView.setTag(vh);
        }

        vh.cat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.update_categore_dialog);
                dialog.setTitle("Update Your Category");
                dialog.show();

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return convertView;

    }
    public class viewholder
    {
        LinearLayout cat;
       
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you tried using `context ` variable instead of `getContext()`??

Comment: What error getting using current code?

Comment: Can you post logcat ?

Comment: i have less than 10 reputation i can't. :(

Comment: i tried but it gives the same error.

Comment: Why don't you post your logcat as text with the question?

Comment: http://s29.postimg.org/f5het9hrr/error.png

here is logcat. @Boss

Comment: Can you post the code of  `CategoryAdapter` call, also are you passing a `getApplicationContext()` to the constructor? Please post that code..

Comment: yes i am passing getApplicationContext() to CategoryAdapter.

Comment: try pass in `YourActivity.this` as context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `context` instead `getContext()`

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
```

Finally, Just pass `context`

```
vh.cat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.update_categore_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Update Your Category");
            dialog.show();

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: A post to get UPVOTE.. no comments, no helping word no explanation

Comment: check 2nd line. ".so" not found

Comment: @AnwarKamal Move ahead .

Comment: can you please check my latest question about firebase

Comment: @AnwarKamal you can share link . I don't have enough knowledge about `firebase` . In spite of i will check logic

Comment: Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38199267/how-can-i-get-arraylist-of-java-objects-of-all-childs-from-firebase

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
 Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.update_categore_dialog);
                dialog.setTitle("Update Your Category");
                dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `getView()` method, Replace `getContext()` with your `context` variable.

```
vh.cat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                //remaining code...
            }
        });
```

And in your initialization of `CateogoryAdapter` don't pass `getApplicationContext()`, instead pass in the context (`Activity.this`) like this.

```
CategoryAdapter adapter = CategoryAdapter(YourActivity.this, menu, menu2, menu3)
```