# How Can I get ArrayList of Java Objects of all Childs from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How Can I get ArrayList of Java Objects of all Childs from Firebase using updated firebase commands, currently I am using below approach but not able to get the list.

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI

                if(dataSnapshot!=null){
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot:        dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        UserDataClass post =    postSnapshot.getValue(UserDataClass.class);
                        members.add(post);
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Getting Post failed, log a message

            }
        };
        mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

> below is datasnapshot which is returning from firebase but I am not able to get the desired result out of it.

```
DataSnapshot { key = 12345, value = {Members={00000000={phoneNo=00000000, longitude=73.0703307, latitude=33.6396975, password=qwertyuiop, CName=00000000, admin=true, name=Anwar Kamal}, 03028084374={phoneNo=03028084374, longitude=73.0701292, latitude=33.6397129, password=qwerty, CName=00000000, admin=false, name=Nehal Khan}, 03028084516={phoneNo=03028084516, longitude=73.0702659, latitude=33.6397622, password=qwerty, CName=03035356317, admin=false, name=Jamal Khan}}} }
```

> all i want is list of all members

[image: FireBase Database Structure]

> and my java object is

```
public class UserDataClass {
     public double latitude;
     public double longitude;
     public String Name="";
     public String password="";
     public String phoneNo="";
     public String CircleName="";
     public boolean isAdmin=false;
}
```

Comment: please post your Firebase data structure

Comment: please check Firebase data structure added

Comment: @AnwarKamal what problem or error you getting?

Comment: no error but getting arrayList with single empty object

Answer (score 1):

The `ValueEventListener` has another purpose.
You should use `ChildEventListener` and also `dataSnapshop.getValue()` to implement what you want, for example:

```
ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

        UserDataClass post =    postSnapshot.getValue(UserDataClass.class);
        members.add(post);
    }

  //...
```

**Note:** 
You should use the listener with the current `firebase_referance` to the `Users` table. Hence you should replace

```
    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

with

```
    mDatabaseRef.child("Members").addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```

notice that your full path of the `Members` table is colored and i couldn't figure the path.

You can find the whole documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#value_events)

good luck

Comment: I have already tried this thing but same result also I have updated my question by adding some information please check again.

Comment: can you add your `mDatabaseRef`? and your `database structure`

Comment: check again I have added my database structure

Comment: mDatabaseRef.child("xxxx").child("xyz").child("Members");

Comment: please check above comment I have provided my complete database reference

Comment: Can you update the code you have until now? After the updates we have done?

Comment: actually i was doing some mistake by not providing complete reference to the child. 
any way thanks for the answer but the error was something else.